# Vaadin - Grid pagination using the token of the last returned record

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am using Vaadin 24. I'd like to paginate rows on a Grid. The way it works is, I call a rest endpoint and it returns a 100 records. I need to hold onto the last row's token. When the user scrolls down I need to call the rest api again with the last row's token and get new records.
How do I implement this with Vaadin Grid?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: You might want to leverage Grid lazy loading feature: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#lazy-loading. In start.vaadin.com, the master-detail view comes with a lazy-loaded Grid, so you might want to download a project with that view to see how it's done.

Comment: Apologies I should have been more specific. The lazy loading feature of Grid provided in the docs makes use of a query with an offset and a limit. These are both geared to work with a database, perhaps. I have a rest api to work with. The rest api needs the last token (a string) to be passed in order to get the next set of data. How can I get this to work?

Comment: I don't have the total number of records that could come back. I only know 100 records at a time do. As and when the user scrolls down the list new records should be fetched from the rest api and shown